# Strange return value of Array after splice this

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when i want dupplicate an object in array.

Example Array:

```
const fruits = [
  {"name": "banana", "index": 0},
  {"name": "orange", "index": 1},
  {"name": "lemon", "index": 2}
];
```

I want to dupplicate 1 fruit and reorder their index with a function;

```
duplicate = (index) => { 
  const newList = [...fruits];

  const newFruit = fruits[index];

  newList.splice(index + 1, 0, newFruit);

  for(let i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
    newList[i].index = i
  };

  return newArray;
};
```

But the function "duplicate(1);" return this:

```
[
  {"name": "banana", "index": 0},
  {"name": "orange", "index": 2},
  {"name": "orange", "index": 2},
  {"name": "lemon", "index": 3}
]
```

Instead of:

```
[
  {"name": "banana", "index": 0},
  {"name": "orange", "index": 1},
  {"name": "orange", "index": 2},
  {"name": "lemon", "index": 3}
]
```

And I don't understand why ?

Comment: because you do not have a copy of the object. It is the same object in two indexes. `newList.splice(index + 1, 0, { ...newFruit });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have incorrectly copied the value of the **array of objects**.

> The spread operator will create a deep copy of the topmost data and a
> shallow copy of the nested data.

```
const newList = [...fruits];
```

so the above line creates a **shallow copy of the array**

**Solution:-**

```
const newFruit = {
    ...fruits[index]
};
```

The above code will get the deep copy of the required object, which will make the program work as expected.

```
const fruits = [
  {"name": "banana", "index": 0},
  {"name": "orange", "index": 1},
  {"name": "lemon", "index": 2}
]

const duplicate = (index) => { 
  const newList = [...fruits];

  const newFruit = {
        ...fruits[index]
    };

  newList.splice(index + 1, 0, newFruit);

  for(let i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
    newList[i].index = i
  };

  return newList;
};
```

Comment: It doesn't create a deep copy of anything, it creates a shallow copy of the array

Answer (score 0):

you returns an empty array because you're not deleting anything,  create a deep copy of the original array using `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` before modifying

```js
const fruits = [
  {"name": "banana", "index": 0},
  {"name": "orange", "index": 1},
  {"name": "lemon", "index": 2}
];

const duplicate = (index) => {
  const newList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fruits)); // create a deep copy of the original array

  const newFruit = newList[index]; // get the fruit to be duplicated

  newList.splice(index + 1, 0, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newFruit))); // insert the duplicated fruit

  for (let i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
    newList[i].index = i;
  }

  console.log(`Original array: ${JSON.stringify(fruits)}`);
  console.log(`New duplicated array: ${JSON.stringify(newList)}`);

  return newList;
};

duplicate(1);
```

Comment: There are better methods of deep cloning that don't risk data loss [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)